# How do I define a safe sqrt function in clojure?

Tags: clojure, genetic-programming

I am using fungp (a genetic programming tool) to model a complex function and having trouble with sqrt.

Basically, I have to pass a vector of functions and their arity into fungp so that it can compose expressions from them. The expressions will then be evaluated and the best one will be returned. This vector of functions looks like:

```
(def functions
  '[[+ 2]
  [- 2]
  [* 2]
  [fungp.util/abs 1]
  [fungp.util/sdiv 2]
  [fungp.util/sin 1]
  [fungp.util/sqrt 1]
  [inc 1]
  [dec 1]])
```

That setup gives me a hundred lines of errors like:

```
#<ClassCastException java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn>
```

Which I believe is due to the definition of fungp.util/sqrt:

```
(defn sqrt [x] (if (x > 0) (Math/sqrt x) 0))
```

I think the 0 is causing the failure to evaluate, but I'm not sure. I've tried defining my own version of the safe square root, but couldn't get the syntax correct.

So, this is where I'm stuck. I need a version of square root that is safe (returns 0 for negative inputs) and evaluates properly in the fungp expression.

EDIT: For completeness, this is one of the (many) variations I've tried for writing my own square root wrapper:

```
(defn sqrt-fn [x] `(if (~x > 0) (Math/sqrt ~x) 0))
```

And the output (the middle bit is the expression that was generated from the functions):

```
#<ClassCastException java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.Cons cannot be cast to java.lang.Number>

(let [] (- (dec (- (- (fungp.util/sin (tutorial.tut1/sqrt-fn 8.0)) (fungp.util/sdiv (* x 2.0) (dec 9.0))) (fungp.util/sdiv (tutorial.tut1/sqrt-fn (* x x)) (- (- x 4.0) (+ x x))))) (fungp.util/sdiv (tutorial.tut1/sqrt-fn (fungp.util/sin (
+ (dec x) (inc x)))) (fungp.util/sdiv (* (inc (inc 1.0)) (* (+ x 9.0) (fungp.util/sin 9.0))) (tutorial.tut1/sqrt-fn (- (tutorial.tut1/sqrt-fn x) (fungp.util/abs 3.0)))))))

NullPointerException   clojure.lang.Numbers.ops (Numbers.java:942)
```

I am not writing the expressions, so if there are extra parentheses or missing parentheses, they are coming from the way that I've defined sqrt.

Comment: i don't think that's the right conclusion to derive from that error. It just means something tried to call 0.0 like it was a function. Typing `(0.0)` into the repl results in the same exception.

Comment: @NathanHughes So, I am stuggling to grasp clojure and I could definitely be wrong, but the reason I think that is the cause of the problem is that if I omit the square root from my functions vector, everything works correctly (except that my function cannot be modeled accurately) and if I use an unsafe square root wrapper the ClassCastExceptions go away, but I get contract exceptions due to the negative numbers.

Comment: I bet the error is in your square root wrapper. Somewhere there is an extra pair of parenthesis. Remember that parens are in clojure for call semantics and list literals, not order of evaluation grouping.

Comment: @NathanHughes Thanks for your suggestions. I was also under the impression that there were extra parenthes, but I can't figure out why/where. I've updated the question with more information about my own wrapper.

Comment: >_<  sqrt needs to be like this : (defn sqrt [x] (if (> x 0) (Math/sqrt x) 0))  -- renounce your infix ways

Comment: @NathanHughes Thanks, I should've known it would be somthing stupid.

Comment: annoyed i didn't see this right off.

Comment: Why is your vector of `functions` quoted? You surely want the functions, not the symbols.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, I was working from a tutorial, but I think it was supposed to be just the symbols as they are later copied into an expression tree and evaluated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with this:

```
(defn sqrt-fn [x] `(if (~x > 0) (Math/sqrt ~x) 0))
```

First, as hinted at in the comments, `(x > 0)` is trying to call `x` (presumably a number) as a function. `>` is the function, so it must come first, as in `(> x 0)`.

Also, you probably don't want they syntax quote here - that prevents evaluation of the contents, so your function is returning a quoted list of symbols.